# url.pathToFileURL is not a function : how to convert a file path to an URL in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I want to convert a file path to an URL.

I tried to follow the indications found in the official docs: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/url.html#urlpathtofileurlpath

```
import { pathToFileURL } from 'url'

let filepathurl = pathToFileURL(file.path)
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _url.pathToFileURL) is not a function
```

Or :

```
import url from 'url'
let filepathurl = url.pathToFileURL(file.path)
```

Error message:

```
_url.default.pathToFileURL is not a function
```

Other info:

```
node: v16.13.0
O.S. : Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop
```

What am I doing wrongly? How to solve the problem?

Example of file path:

```
/home/raphy/Downloads/sample.pdf
```

At the moment, I solved the problem using https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-url combined with this helpful suggestion for webpack configuration: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11764#issuecomment-1104019653

But I would like to know if and how to correctly use the features of the node.js library

Comment: Check the contents of `file.path`. Using a string literal Instead your first code snippets runs without errors under node 16.13.0 on win10 if the source code file extension is `.mjs` (though I get an error  different from yours when switching to `.js`.

Comment: Thank you @collapsar for helping. Example of file path:  /home/raphy/Downloads/sample.pdf . Anyway, at the moment, I solved the problem using https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-url combined with this helpful suggestion for webpack configuration: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11764#issuecomment-1104019653